# How to pass props in a component Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props

My component:

```
interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<any> {
      sample: {
        info: SampleInfo;
      };
    }
    export class Step extends Component<Props, State>{
    render() {
        const { title } = this.props.sample.info;
        return (
           <TextContent >
              <Title headingLevel="h1" size="3xl">
               Uploading and validating your swagger : {name}  // name is available under sample.info 
              </Title>
            </TextContent>
    )}
    }
```

When I am trying to access props, I am getting this.props.sample is undefined.

I am trying to call this Step Component in a wizard:

```
const steps = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "show",
        component: <Form />,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Listing",
        component: <Sample2 />,
      },

      { name: "Save", component: <Step/>}, // I am calling my Step component from here
    ];
```

Do I need to pass anything in Step component, please help me with this. I am new to reactjs

Comment: How are you rendering steps information

Comment: It's a part of the wizard. So whenever I click on the save button , Component Step gets render. But i am getting error there as, this.props.sample is undefined.

Comment: You should pass what you expect to receive inside Step component

Comment: Which is that wizard component

Comment: Can you see Const steps in my question, that is the part of the wizard

Comment: That is just data that you would supply to some component, but which is that component, how does it render this data is the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `<Step/>` component must actually have `props`.

It must pass something like `<Step sample={{ info: { title: 'whatever' } }}/>` then it'll work.

Comment: so do i need to declare props in other component also, from where I am rendering <Step> ?

Comment: idk about that. your `Steps` component expects prop as written `this.props.sample.info` so you need to pass `Steps` a `sample` prop to it

Answer (score 0):

`RouteComponentProps` from `react-router` is defined as:

```js
export interface RouteComponentProps<
    Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string } = {},
    C extends StaticContext = StaticContext,
    S = H.LocationState
> {
    history: H.History<S>;
    location: H.Location<S>;
    match: match<Params>;
    staticContext?: C;
}
```

(Source: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-router/index.d.ts#L70)

Due to `extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string }` and you specifying
`Params` generic as `any` (via `RouteComponentProps<any>`), `K` may be any key and because of the `?` the value for all keys may be `undefined`.

I do not use `react-router` but I think you have to specify `RouteComponentProps` using appropriate values fot the generic parameters.

Comment: To be clear, my answer just handles the TypeScript error which I suppose you refer to.